# How can I uninstall an old version after changing the upgrade code?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have 2 programs(A and B) with the same upgrade code - when one is installing the other one is uninstalled.
Now I have to install both programs on the same machine, in order to do that I changed the upgrade code from one program(A)
My problem is that if I already have an old version of A installed on my pc MSI doesn't recognize the new upgrade code and makes a new install. How can I uninstall the old version? Is there a way to do that from installShield?
I tried to make a custom script :

```
    LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas";
    MessageBox("result incercam uninstall",INFORMATION);
    command_e = "wmic product where \"description='IP Office Admin Lite'\"  uninstall";
    LaunchApplication( "cmd.exe",
     "/C " + command_e,
      "", 
                    SW_MINIMIZE, 0, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT );
```

But somehow it doesn't work everytime, I think is has something to do with timing.
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> ***Upgrade Table***: Provided this is an MSI - which it should be since you mention upgrade code - you can generally uninstall any
> existing installation by means of authoring [the upgrade table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/upgrade-table) of the
> MSI you are installing.
>
> In fact this is the way you should do it, and not rely on any custom action constructs since they tend to cause problems. This is MSI's built in ["major upgrade" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/major-upgrades) intended to deliver upgrades for your own products

Please see the technical explanations here:

- [Remove other software on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522088/remove-other-software-on-installation/53530111#53530111)
- [Adding entries to MSI UpgradeTable to remove related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801570/adding-entries-to-msi-upgradetable-to-remove-related-products/51803320#51803320)

In Installshield you should just add the older upgrade code in [the Upgrades view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169278/129130) ([`Installshield help file`](https://docs.flexera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/Upgrades.htm)), but I don't have Installshield available to try it at the moment. The linked answers with WiX constructs should show the overall procedure.